# Drupal 7: Menu item being accessed even with false access callback?

Tags: users

I have a menu item:

```
$items['login-now'] = array
(
    'title' => 'Log In',
    'page callback' => 'some_or_other_method',
    'access callback' => 'the_permissions_function',
    'menu_name' => 'menu-ecommerce-nav',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => '5',
);
```

And then I have:

```
function the_permissions_function { 
    $isAnonymousUser = user_is_anonymous();
    if (!$isAnonymousUser) {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    return TRUE;
}
```

This works if I am logged out. I can see the "log in" button. But when I log in, it STILL shows this login button. Why?

What's interesting is, I added this above the "return false"

```
print 'xxxx'; die();
```

And it hits this code!! But for some reason, it still shows the menu item? Why is it not hiding the menu item?

**UPDATE**

Even if I just do this:

```
'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
```

It STILL shows the "log in" menu item when I am LOGGED in. Why on earth is it doing this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

user_is_anonymous() returns TRUE if the user is a menu administrator: see [function user_is_anonymous](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/7)

Try user_is_logged_in() instead, e.g.:

```
function the_permissions_function { 
    $isLoggedIn = user_is_logged_in();
    if ($isLoggedIn) {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your menu gets cached, so you need to clear the caches after you change something in you hook_menu() or hook_menu_alter().